# Google Sheets for an Automated Shift Bid Process

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace-for-business

Hello I am looking for some help because I don't know how to go about this and have been unable to find any resources that guide me on doing what I am trying to do.

So I work for an organization that is trying to bring our shift bid process into the 21st century. I have made some progress by creating a Google Form that submits straight to a Google Sheet. I am trying to make the sheet essentially automate the process and place people according to their seniority in the company.

Here is what I have so far.

The form has three basic questions such as "Seniority Number", "1st-6th bid choice", and "an acknowledgment that their choices are correct." Upon submitting the form a macro runs that will sort the data from highest in seniority to lowest in seniority. The form has conditional formatting set up for the different shifts and I was able to get a checkbox set up to essentially blackout shifts for when we go to check and make sure the automation was correct.

Now... What I am having an issue with...

I have been unsuccessful in figuring out how to get a formula to check each bid choice and see if there is space available.

Example:

All six shifts have 4 slots available.
The first five people have their first choice as A-Days. Unfortunately, that fifth person can't be on that shift because there are already four slots filled. I then need it to check is second choice and if that shift is filled his third and so on all the way up to a sixth choice.

From there I would want it to place all of the people's names into the respective scheduling spot.

Some insight or guidance would be greatly appreciated. I know this is a lot to ask, but I would love to help my organization with this and bring some innovation here.

Here is my sheet so far:
[ShiftBidSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rlocPK5QUYq1s4HLNInAWS9W1sXyKkG28WsULWDRA20/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome. Would you clarify how many actual staff you have? I assume the test data (13 staff) is just a sample. Regarding the 5th person, there appears to be some logical inconsistencies. You said " I then need it to check [h]is second choice and if that shift is filled, his third and so on all the way up to a sixth choice." Might this result in the 5th person getting preference over every other employee, including higher seniority, and others who listed earlier preferences. Consider "08-01": he is 5th for "A-Days", 5th for "A-Graves", 5th for "B-Swings", etc - what shift would you assign him?

Comment: So seniority is the most important. If an employee is lowest in seniority he is most likely going to get his last valid choice. For example if the first 5 people choose A days the 5th person will get their second choice. So the choices are where people want to be placed based on their preference. We have 6 shifts of four. I was trying to automate it as the form as it is submitted by employees. Does that help clarify.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. Would you please edit your spreadsheet to show the shifts that would be assigned for a successful outcome of shifts assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to automate the allocation of shifts to workers. There are several factors:

- 6 shift types
- six shift preferences/choices per worker
- only four workers can be assigned to any given shift
- workers are assigned shifts by seniority

There may be several ways to answer your question, consider this as one solution to your problem.

---

**Sample**

The table shows the allocation of the 1st to 6th shift choice, and a final column showing the actual "Assigned Shifts".

- All formulas are entered in row 3 and copied down to the bottom of the worker choices
- Each choice consists of 2 columns, the "SHIFT" and a running total by "Shift".

### [image: screenshot]

**1st choice** SHIFT = `+D3`

- the workers first shift choice.

**1st choice** COUNT = `=countif($N$3:N3,N3)`

- To create a running total by shift, the first part of the range is absolute and the second part is relative; as the formula is copied down, the range expands.

**2nd choice** SHIFT = `=if(O3<=4," ",E3)`

- if the previous choice was valid ("<4"), then a space is entered, otherwise the workers 2nd choice is selected.

**2nd choice** COUNT = `=if(P3=" ",0,countif($P$3:P3,P3))`

- if the selection is a space, then the value is zero, otherwise a running total is created. Notice how the totals only appear for the shifts that were previous invalid (highlighted in pink).
- The formula in the rest of the columns is a case of rinse and repeat.

**3rd choice** SHIFT = `=if(Q3<=4," ",F3)`

**3rd choice** COUNT = `=if(R3=" ",0,countif($R$3:R3,R3))`

**4th choice** SHIFT = `=if(S3<=4," ",G3)`

**4th choice** COUNT = `=if(T3=" ",0,countif($T$3:T3,T3))`

**5th choice** SHIFT = `=if(U3<=4," ",H3)`

**5th choice** COUNT = `=if(V3=" ",0,countif($V$3:V3,V3))`

**6th choice** SHIFT = `=if(W3<=4," ",I3)`

**6th choice** COUNT = `=if(X3=" ",0,countif($X$3:X3,X3))`

**ASSIGNED SHIFT** = `=index(N3:Y3,0,(match(maxifs(N3:Y3,N3:Y3,"<5"),N3:Y3,0))-1)`

- This formula uses `match` to find the maximum value (`maxifs`) across the row where the value is "<5" (the shift is a valid choice). Match returns an index value, and the `index` component of the formula enables selection of the cell to the left of the matched cell - it returns the shift name.

Below the shift choices is a small group of subtotals by shift type (row 18 to 23). If count>4, the value is highlighted - though this is a visual indicator only

- the formula is `=countif($N$3:$N$15,N18)`

---

**EXAMPLE**

- In "1st Choice", 5 workers chose "A Days" and 6 workers chose "B Graves".
- When the shift count is greater than 4, Conditional formatting is applied to highlight the unsuccessful choice. The formatting is merely a visual indicator, shifts are assigned by formula in subsequent columns.
- In "2nd choice" and subsequent columns, if a worker's previous selection was 5th and higher, then their "2nd" (or later) choice applies.
- The running total is calculated to make sure that the selection is not 5th or higher.

[Example spreadsheet:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wXmc3fPGqT5yiaOvP7Vpw9o04QbvEH1AqWGVrKdiV04/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is immensely helpful, I think I have a good step in the direction that I would need to head for this. I like your take on it. I appreciate the help! I like that it is keeping a running total and if the first choice is over filled it begins counting in the next column. Do to the sheer size I don't think I will be able to implement this right away, but rather maybe the next time when we bid in 3 months again I will be able to! Thanks again!